# On automorphisms

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm using the 9.0 version and I'm trying to compute automorphism groups of graphs, but when I type GraphAutomorphismGroup[G], I just get the same as output GraphAutomorphismGroup, even if I load the Combinatorica package, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In MMA 12.1: g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}];  GraphAutomorphismGroup[g] gives: PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}]}]

Comment: Hello Daniel, just in your example I get GraphAutomorphismGroup[
 Graph[{2 1[UndirectedEdge], 3 2[UndirectedEdge], 3[UndirectedEdge]}]]

Comment: Your are right. By copy and past, the backslash were deleted. I try again: g=Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3,  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}]; GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?"  You are using version 9.0. `GraphAutomorphismGroup` was introduced in version 10.0. It is not present in 9.0. You can see this in the documentation. Combinatorica contains the `Automorphisms` function instead. It will be very slow and not very useful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is fundamentally a feature issue where V9 doesn't have something added in a future version; there is nothing this site can do to fix it short of reimplementing the functionality

Answer (score 0):

if I copy and paste the code into a comment, the backlashes get deleted. Therefore, I am trying it here:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}];
GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]
```

Now it should work. I copied it back to MMA and checked it.